# Unable to find timed publication button in google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I want to publish my android app update at a specific date but I can't find the timed publication button in google play console. I followed this help page :
 https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9543912?hl=fr&ref_topic=7072031&authuser=0
 but I found nothing.
I think it is because of the changes of the console's new UI..
Any idea ?

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming question, as it is expected on StackOverflow, but it's about a Google product I think. Maybe you want to contact other specialized google groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're searching for this:

[image: Button "Publication planifiée"]

Comment: I also don't have it displayed. I've displayed thoses pages on Firefox and Chrome and have the same problem (no such button is displayed). Any idea of what I should do to get it ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I never used that function